# Writing multiple items with the same tag in a CSV file in one column

Tags: xml, csv

So I have to convert an XML file to a CSV file by hand and need to know how to write an entry when I have a situation like this:

```
<person>
    <name>Joe Smith</name>
    <email>Joe@gmail.com</email>
    <email>Joe@outlook.com</email>
    <email>Joe@yahoo.com</email>
    <age>26</age>
</person>
```

I believed it would be something like:

```
Joe Smith, "Joe@gmail.com, Joe@outlook.com, Joe@yahoo.com", 26
```

But it seems wrong to me.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does it will not contain xml declaration??

Comment: That's just a snippet of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no “correct” way. If an amount of emails is limited to, say, three (whoever needs more? :), I would go with fields like “email1”, “email2” and “email3”. This approach is better, because later on the consumer of this csv might just pick the value up from the cell and expect there is a valid email, without any redundant format checks and splits.

On the other hand, whether it’s significant to preserve all emails, and there could be, say, 20 of them, the approach would be to have two fields, like “primary email” and “other emails.” Then `"Joe@gmail.com"` goes to the first field, `"Joe@outlook.com Joe@yahoo.com"` — to the second one, and in most cases the consumer is fine with reading just the first field.

Please note I do not use comma to split emails, just a space, since email can not contain spaces itself. Easy parsing!

If you still want to have the only field for email, just get rid of comma as emails delimiter (and, therefore, quotes):

```
Joe Smith, Joe@gmail.com Joe@outlook.com Joe@yahoo.com, 26
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!